# ¿Como usar paso de parametros por referencia(retorno) y valor con matriz para imprimir el calculo al cuadrado?

Tags: java

Hoy en clase me dejaron el programa de:

> Hacer un programa que almacene numeros positivos en una matriz de 3x3.
>
> Calcular el cuadrado de cada numero almacenando los resultados en otra
> matriz.
>
> Imprimir la segunda matriz.

Lo termine pero hay un solo error que me marca en la linea de `matR=Calcular();`

Anexo el codigo, por favor,seria de mucha ayuda,pues no es la primera vez que me pasa con este tipo de parametros y ya me estoy desesperando.

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class PRACTICA10 {
  public static void Lectura() {
    int mat[][] = new int[3][3];

    int c, f;
    for (f = 0; f < mat.length; f++) {
      for (c = 0; c < mat.length; c++) {
        mat[f][c] = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese el numero"));

      }
    }
    Calcular(mat);
  }
  public static int[][] Calcular(int[][] mat) {
    int f, c;
    int matR[][] = new int[3][3];
    for (f = 0; f < matR.length; f++) {
      for (c = 0; c < matR.length; c++) {
        matR[f][c] = (int)Math.pow(mat[f][c], 2);
      }
    }
    return matR;
  }
  public static void Imprimir(int matR[][]) {
    int f, c;
    String mensaje = " ";
    for (f = 0; f < matR.length; f++) {
      for (c = 0; c < matR.length; c++) {
        mensaje = mensaje + matR[f][c] + " ";
      }
    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, mensaje);
  }
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    int matR[][] = new int[3][3];
    matR = Calcular();
    Imprimir(matR);
  }
}
```

Comment: Y el parámetro de entrada para la función Calcular??? En main has creado la matriz matR, no has llamado a la función que te rellena la matriz, aunque tampoco recibe ni retorna nada esa función, con lo que no te sirve para nada, y tampoco se la pasas a Calcular como parámetro de entrada. Obviamente te falla compilando. En resumen: La función Lectura no hace nada ni la llamas, la función Calcular no la estás llamando bien.

Answer (score 1):

Tenes varios errores. Acá va una posible forma de hacerlo.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class PruebaMatriz {

    private static int matR[][];

    public static void inicializarMatriz() {
        matR =new int[3][3];
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //matR=Calcular();//daba error de compilación por que el método Calcular(int[][] mat)
        //lo tenías preparado recibir un parámetro (int[][] mat) y no se lo estabass pasando
        //Nota: a este método le cambié el nombre por CalcularPotencia, para que
        //sea más representativo y además le quité el parámetro ya que no tiene sentido al
        //declarar la mariz matR como atributo. De igual modo, a lectura() le cambié el nombre por cargarMatriz().
        //Tanto el atributo matR como los métodos, son estáticos para no tener que crear un objeto PruebaMatriz.
        inicializarMatriz();
        cargarMatriz();
        imprimir(getMatR());
        //ahora declaramos e inicializamos una nueva matriz para guardar la potencia de matR
        int matAlCuadrado[][];
        //le asignamos calcularPotencia()
        matAlCuadrado =calcularPotencia();
        imprimir(matAlCuadrado);
    }
    //getter
    public static int[][] getMatR() {
        return matR;
    }
    //como buena práctica, los nombres de los métodos comienzan con minúscula
    public static void cargarMatriz(){
        int c,f;
        for(f=0;f<matR.length;f++){
            //acá hacías matR.length y funcionaba bien por que en este caso el número de
            //filas es igual al de columnas, pero si la matriz por ej. llegara a ser de 3X2 ya está mal,
            //así que la forma correcta es: matR[f].length
            for(c=0;c<matR[f].length;c++){
                //como el usuario puede ingresar un caracter no numérico, y por lo tanto el método
                //Integer.parseInt() arrojará una excepción de tipo NumberFormatException, hay que controlar
                //dicha excepción con un bloque try catch
                try{
                    matR[f][c]=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese el numero"));
                }
                catch(NumberFormatException ex){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Debe ingresar valores numéricos\n"
                           + ex,"Excepción",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    c--;//retrocedemos el contador
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public static int[][] calcularPotencia(){
        int f,c;
        int newMatR[][]=new int[3][3];
        for(f=0;f<matR.length;f++){
            for(c=0;c<matR[f].length;c++){
                newMatR[f][c]=(int)Math.pow(matR[f][c],2);
            }
        }
        return newMatR;
    }/**
     * Imprime matriz pasada por parámetro
     * @param mat Matriz bidimensional de enteros
     */
    public static void imprimir(int mat[][]){
        int f,c;
        String mensaje=" ";
        for(f=0;f<mat.length;f++){
            for(c=0;c<mat[f].length;c++){
                mensaje=mensaje+mat[f][c]+" ";
            }
        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,mensaje);
    }
}
```